# Check Box Limit max no. of selection based on cell Value in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

Please Help me,

I need to limit Max no. of tick box/checkbox selection in a column.
1. Max no. of selection for a department to be limited.
2. Tick Box selection limit to be controlled by a Cell Value for each department

Sample file is attached here
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12oXmjM1P61nCk6JjKDDHtYH0TPZDF7jcPII4srpDsHk).

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can use this script into Data > Scripteditor.
This will check after every edit how many checkboxes are true in column 14 (which is column N in your sheet). If it reached a limit (I set it at 10) it sets a protection on column 14, which can only be change by you. It also sets the backgroundcolor to red for the whole column, indicating it can't ben changed by anyone but you.

```html
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Full List'); 
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 14,lr,1); //column 14 is column N in your sheet
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  var count = 0;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    
    if( data[i] == 'true')
    {
      count++;
    }
  }
  
  var rangeColum = e.range;//The range of cells edited
  
  var columnOfCellEdited = rangeColum.getColumn();//Get column number
  
  if (count >= 10 && columnOfCellEdited == 14) //you can change the number 10 into any number you want to set the max to
  {
    range.protect().setDescription('reached max number of checks');
    range.setBackground('#f4c7c3')
  } 
}
```

Using [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) from Apps Script reference

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column after R, which you'll later hide. 
In that column you can write in R2: =COUNTIF(N:N;TRUE). This will count how often there's a TRUE (=checkbox selected). 
Then you could add a Conditional Format (see picture below), turning the whole column red if the max number of checks has been reached. In this example I maxed it at equal or greater than 10.

It doesn't restrict people from checking more boxes, but the color should say enough imo. 
If you really want to block people from adding more checks, you should look into using Google App Script.

[image: add a conditional format]

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but I need to restrict the user from selecting max. no. of selection

Comment: If you're familiar with Google App script, you can use my new answer as a way to really protect the range from editing by anyone but yourself.